# What is the "%%" arithmetic in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

Sorry if this is a bit of a dummy question, but I have no idea what the %% arithmetic is. When I set `a` to `30 %% 35`, it sets `a` to the value 30. But if I switch the numbers around, it sets `a` to the value 5. I just don't understand this.

```
@echo off
set /a a=30 %% 35
echo %a%
pause
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`%%` is the **modulus** operator - that is, it performs integer division of its left argument by its right argument, and returns the *remainder*. [SS64 on `SET`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) explains all of the allowed operators in the [arithmetic `SET` command](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html#expressions).

As @IvanMilyakov indicated in the comments, if you are doing a `SET /A ...` from the command line directly, rather than in a batch file, you would use `%` instead of `%%`; within a batch file, you need to double it to prevent it from being treated as a variable escape.

Comment: +1 for the link to SS64, it's the best reference/learning resource I've come across for batch file scripting.

Comment: To be precise, `%` is the operator; it only needs to be doubled inside a batch file

Answer (score 8):

`A % B` at the prompt is `A %% B` in a batch, because the `%` symbol is special and needs to be 'escaped' in a batch. In the case of the `%` character, the escape character is another `%` character.

As Jeff Zeitlin says, the `%` or `%%` operator is the modulus operator, and gives the remainder after dividing A by B so `35 % 30` gives 5 because when you divide 35 by 30 you get the answer 1 and 5 left over, also you would get 5 from `65 % 30`, `95 % 30` and so on. If B is larger than A the result of `A % B` will always be A. This is why `30 % 35` returns 30.

You can try `set /a` operations at the prompt. Try `set /a 8%7` and see what you get. You don't need spaces.